# Get cell by its content

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there a way to get the cell object or coordinate by the data the cell contains?

For example if the cell with coordinates (1;5) contains the string `"FINDME"`, i'd like to do something like Workbook.GetCellByData("FINDME") and it should return the Cell object or (1;5).

I have found a [code snippet](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) on the Apache POI website that could be useful. I could just read the whole workbook and find the data with an IF-statement, but that's kind of dirty...

**EDIT**:
I have coded the "dirty" solution as follows:

```
public Cell getCellByContent(String data) {
    for (Row row : wb.getSheetAt(0)) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {           
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                System.out.println(String.format("Found String type at (%s,%s) and read: %s", row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getStringCellValue()));
                if (cell.getStringCellValue() == data) { //HERE
                    return cell;                         //HERE
                }                                        //HERE
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Can't find it bruh!");
    return null;
```

For some reason it fails at the if-statement. Id like to get the Cell with the content `"%title%"`.

Output:

```
Found String type at (0,0) and read: %title% <------ IT'S RIGHT HERE!
Found String type at (2,0) and read: Test Information
...
Can't find it bruh!
```

Does someone have an idea why this is not working?

Comment: It may be dirty, but if it isn't a feature provided by the API or a feature of an object provided by the API (like a hypothetical Workbook.getMap()) then dirty all that is left. @RainDrops solution is the best one I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the dirty solution replace

`if (cell.getStringCellValue() == data)`

with

`if (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(data))`

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help you. you just make two for() loops for rows and columns and then type Workbook.getCellValue(i,j) (i is the number of the row and j is the number of the column

Comment: Not that i am too familiar with the coding but why  are you using this
 `if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){` cell.getStringCellValue returns you the cell  content as a string.You just have to check if the content is the same as as the "data" you are looking for. Or i am misunderstanding something